# Can I do ssh and do for loop and touch files in a single shot?

Tags: ssh, control-flow

```sh
for account in ${accounts}
do
        `ssh -q id@server "touch EVENTS_${account}_${date}.log"`
done
```

Instead of doing ssh so many times, can I just do ssh and run the for loop and touch the files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ssh allows you to execute multiple commands. Simply separate each command with a semi-colon.

```sh
command=": "
for account in ${accounts}
do
        command=$command"; touch EVENTS_${account}_${date}.log"
done
ssh -q id@server "$command"
```

All the ": " does is says "proceed to the next command." It's so you're not starting your command with a semi-colon.

Also, you don't need backticks around that command.

Answer (score 0):

Run the loop on the remote machine.

```
ssh -q id@server "for account in ${accounts}; do touch EVENTS_\${account}_${date}.log; done"
```

Note that I assume that `$accounts` and `$date` don't contain any shell special characters (`` "$'()&;<>[\]`{|}~ ``). In paricular, `$accounts` will be interpolated into the remote shell then interpreted there. If you need to protect special characters, you need to be more careful with the quoting:

```
q=\'\\\'\'  # '\'' effectively quotes a single quote inside single quotes
ssh -q id@server 'for account in '\'"${accounts//\'/$q}"\''; do touch "EVENTS_${account}_${date}.log"; done'
```

Alternatively, mount the remote filesystem with [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) and work on it as you would locally.

```
mkdir mnt
sshfs id@server mnt
for account in ${accounts}; do touch "mnt/EVENTS_\${account}_${date}.log"; done
```

Comment: This is a little trickier because you have to escape the '$'. `touch EVENTS_\${account}_${date}.log` ought to work if ${date} is defined on the system calling ssh in the first place. Escaping prevents ${account} from being interpreted locally.

Answer (score 0):

[Cluster ssh](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/clusterssh/index.php?title=Main_Page) seems like the perfect tool for what you are trying to do.

> ClusterSSH is a tool for making the same change on multiple servers at
>   the same time. The 'cssh' command opens an administration console and
>   an xterm to all specified hosts. Any text typed into the
>   administration console is replicated to all windows. All windows may
>   also be typed into directly.
>
> This tool is intended for (but not limited to) cluster administration
>   where the same configuration or commands must be run on each node
>   within the cluster. Performing these commands all at once via this
>   tool ensures all nodes are kept in sync.